# How to compare date in mysql with index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

my friends,

Currently, I was stuck at the query string to compare the date in MySQL with indexing.

created_at type in table is TimeSTAMP and the value is time string. index_name = created_ato on the same table.

- If I tried with created_at = '2020-12-21' then it can use the index but the value is empty cause the created_at is storing at the datetime value.
- If I tried with date(created_at) = '2020-12-21' then it can return the data but the index can not apply, so the time to response so slow and got timeout.

Can anyone know about it and give me some advice on how to it fix it?

Many thanks?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the query, and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` -- "range" is not always bad; let's see the details.

Comment: Hi @RickJames, It seems I found out the root cause on how to fix it. The reason is we have indexing, but it did not cover on this case, so I adding more index to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

What about using:

```
created_at BETWEEN '2020-12-21 00:00:00' AND '2020-12-21 23:59:59.999'
```

or perhaps:

```
created_at >= '2020-12-21' AND created_at  < '2020-12-21' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: Hi bro. Yah I tried, but then the index type will be `range` it means the query will be really slow!

Comment: @Jason These queries should work with the index, they are comparing the field value to date literals.

Comment: I tried to run the queries many times but not luck @giorgos :(. Can I share my screen then you can take a look?

Comment: @Jason Yes, I can have a look if you like

Comment: @Jason - It sounds like there is something else in the `WHERE` clause.  Please show us.

Comment: Hi @RickJames, It seems I found out the root cause on how to fix it. The reason is we have indexing, but it did not cover on this case, so I adding more index to make it works.

Comment: @Jason - Either provide your own answer or Delete the Question.

Comment: @RickJames Yes sure. The answer is I combine 2 columns (created_at and id) and create a new index for it. Then the queries can understand the indexing. Before I add the single index for each created_at and id, but the index can not understand due to the query are using both of them (not only one).